# Find duplicate rows, then remove one of them

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

I have the following query that shows duplicate rows:

```
SELECT ID, user_login, wp_users.user_email FROM wp_users
INNER JOIN (SELECT wp_users.user_email FROM wp_users
GROUP BY wp_users.user_email HAVING count(ID) > 1) dup ON wp_users.user_email = dup.user_email
```

I've only been able to find queries that remove both of them instead of just removing one of them (say the one with the highest ID).

Any ideas?

Comment: pretty sure that's one that removes both duplicates

Comment: @MotiveKyle Check the accepted answer. Don't be sure until you check.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this sql to delete duplicate rows:

```
delete from users where id not in (select min(id) from users group by user_email)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM 
table_name A
WHERE  a.rowid >  ANY ( SELECT B.rowid
                        FROM table_name B
                        WHERE A.col1 = B.col1 AND 
                              A.col2 = B.col2
                       );
```

I guess this will work